# Django - Changing inline formset textInput size attribute

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have an inline formset that only has three fields:

```
class Estimate_Product_Details(models.Model):
    proposalID = models.ForeignKey(Estimate_Construction, verbose_name='Proposal ID')
    CID = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name = 'CID')
    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 7, decimal_places = 2, verbose_name = 'Quantity')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s -- %s' % (self.proposalID, self.CID)
```

I then create a form from that model:

```
class Product_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Estimate_Product_Details
        fields = ('CID', 'qty')
        widgets = {
            'qty' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':30})
            }
```

My goal is to have the `qty` input field really small (I have 30 there for testing). However, when I render this form via an inline formset, the attribute is not being set at all. Here's the creation of the formset in my view:

```
    pFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Estimate_Construction, Estimate_Product_Details, form = Product_Form)
```

Where am I going wrong? Why doesn't the `qty` field change in size?

Comment: have you tried width instead of size?

Comment: @karthikr: yes, I did try width with no luck. Also tried cols (textareas use cols and rows) just for the heck of it.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: It should probably just set a class to the input field and have the CSS assign the width. That way you could pass it to separate templates and such for different clients.

Perhaps instead of using `.attrs['size'] = 30` use `.attrs['class'] = 'some_class'` then define the class in your HTML template and handle the different sizes there.

This should work:

```
class Product_Form(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['qty'].widget.attrs['size'] = 30

    class Meta:
        model = Estimate_Product_Details
        fields = ('CID', 'qty')
```

Comment: Did you get an error? The way I would handle this would be through jQuery, but adding the widget attrs should work from the constructor.

Comment: No, no error - the page just loaded without any hint that somethine was wrong (got me wondering if I was styling the wrong form, which I wasn't). Interesting idea re jQuery. I'll check into that. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: jQuery: `$('id-qty').attr('size', 30);` Weird it would not work in the constructor. Alternately, you can manipulate from the view code, manually: `form = Product_Form(instance=p)`, followed by `form.fields['qty'].widget.attrs = {'size': 30}`

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems with @Furbeenator's code. However, on checking the resulting HTML, I found the `size` attribute was being appended to the `<input>` tag correctly.

The problem: I was using a third-party template which was overriding the `<input>` width with its own CSS definition.

The solution is to pass the width as a `style` attribute rather than `size`:

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company'].widget.attrs['style'] = "width:500px"
```

This modification also works for @Furbeenator's View modification. I did not try the JQuery variant (although the template uses JQuery, I'm not at the moment).

The only downside is that the field width is now defined in terms of CSS units such as pixels or em/ex. I'm going to switch to ex, but it would be nice if CSS had an "average character width" unit so that  you can define boxes like this to "hold 20 chars",etc.

Comment: To use a style, I would suggest not using an inline style tag, but adding a class property to the input box. That way it is all handled in the HTML CSS side. The View code should really be separate from the display, so probably the class attribute would be best, IMHO.

Comment: In the general case this makes sense - I agree about splitting the view from the display. I have an existing template to work with - so far I have not wanted to mess with its CSS files.

Comment: I hear that. Sometimes a workaround is the best answer for the current problem scope.

Comment: That's a smart workaround I'd say. Had the same issue, i.e, the size was applied to the input tag but was overridden by a third party styling definition.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to add a css class name for each input of form. To do it you should add widget attr to your definition of form input. Like bellow:

```
field_name = forms.CharField(label='label', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-control'}))
```