# How can I change the size of text in an input field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to set the font size for text input into a form to be larger when viewed on a mobile. To do this, i've added a font-size attribute to the widget attrs but it doesn't make any difference to the text being input.

```
class MyMobileForm(forms.Form):

    answer = forms.CharField(label="Answer",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus',
                                      'autocomplete': 'off',
                                      'size': '40',
                                      'font-size': 'xx-large',
                                      }))
```

The font-size attribute only affects the label, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have blocked the font size in your css file!

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13612408/3001761?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`font-size` is a **style** property:

```
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus',
                                  'autocomplete': 'off',
                                  'size': '40',
                                  'style': 'font-size: xx-large',
                                  })
```

But it is much better to use the real CSS instead of ad-hoc styling.  Set the `class` attribute to your widget and then define the rule in the `<style>` tag of external `.css` file.